# Duda con el codigo de sumar y sacar el factorial en Java

Tags: java, factorial

Estoy empezando con el lenguaje de programación Java y estoy muy verde, el primer ejercicio ya me trae dolor de cabeza, tengo un problema a resolver con este código, porque no se como realmente funciona, tenia que sumar todos los números del 1 al 100 e hice esto

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int suma = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        suma = suma + i;
    }
    System.out.println(suma);
}
```

El ejercicio sale bien, pero no entiendo como funciona, el bucle en for si lo tengo claro, pero lo de la suma = suma + i me trae de cabeza porque no se como lo hace, ¿baja el numero del bucle a i y despues lo suma con el 0 del int suma? Si cambio el int suma = 0 por int suma 1 me da de resultado 5051, ¿por que suma 1 mas? no tengo ni idea, dejo otro ejemplo sacando el factorial de 5:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Factorial de 5!
    int factorial = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }
    System.out.println(factorial);
}
```

En este la misma duda, y si cambio el int factorial a 0 el resultado es 0, ¿multiplica a todos por 0?

¿Alguien que me resuelva esta duda?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: cuando haces suma = suma +1 estas actualizando el valor de suma y guardandolo en la misma variable. asi que si empiezas con 0 va como  1,2,3,,4 ... pero si empiezas en 1 va 2,3,4,5  .. por eso acaba en 5051 porque empezaste con un valor mas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un bucle for es una iteración. Cuando indicas:

```
int suma = 0
int factorial = 1
```

Lo que haces es inicializar estas variables, es decir, darles un valor inicial.

Un bucle `for` funciona de la siguiente manera. Tienes tres parámetros.

- El primero indica desde dónde empieza la iteración
- El segundo parámetro cuantas veces va a repetir la iteración
- El tercer parámetro va a ser un contador

En cada iteracción, cuando pones `i++` la variable `i` va aumentando. Por lo tanto en tu bucle voy a hacer las tres primeras iteraciones:

- Cuando entra al bucle la suma es igual a 0.
- La variable i es igual a 1  (lo has indicado en el primer parámetro)
- `suma = suma + i` Sumará el valor que tengas actualmente almacenado en la variable `suma` más el valor actual de la variable `i`

Para las tres primeras iteraciones:

```
suma = suma + i; //suma = 0 + 1   --> suma = 1
suma = suma + i; //suma = 1 + 2   --> suma = 3
suma = suma + i; //suma = 3 + 3   --> suma = 6
```

De la misma manera funciona para el factorial. En el factorial no puedes inicializar la variable a 0 porque cualquier valor multiplicado por cero siempre va a devolver cero y por lo tanto cuando hagas

```
factorial = factorial * i
```

El valor anterior de `factorial` multiplicado para cualquier valor de `i` va a ser igual a cero.

Comment: Y por ejemplo, si quiero que me muestre todos los resultados de las operaciones? es decir, con el ejemplo de la suma, que mostrara 1, 3, 6,.........,5050, que código sencillo tendría que añadir?

Comment: En vez de realizar el `System.out.println(suma);` fuera del bucle lo podrías poner justo después de realizar la suma (dentro del bucle). De esta manera podrás ver la suma en cada una de las iteraciones.

Answer (score 2):

No se si te ayude a entenderlo mejor, pero mira.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int suma = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
            int valorQueSumo = i;// Empieza en 1, porque tu has puesto "int i = 1".
            int valorDeSumaAnterior = suma;// Empieza con valor 0.
            // En la primera pasada, valorQueSumo = 1.
            suma = valorDeSumaAnterior + valorQueSumo;

            // La variable i aumenta de 1 en 1, ya que has puesto: i++, lo que aumenta de 1 en 1.
            // Para que veas:
            /*
             * Primera pasada del bucle: 
             * valorQueSumo = 1, porque i = 1.
             * valorDeSumaAnterior = 0, porque aún suma, no ha cambiado.
             * suma = 0 + 1; la suma cambia y ahora pasa a valer 1.
             */
            /*
             * Segunda pasada del bucle:
             * Al ser la segunda pasada, se ha ejecutado i++ una vez, por tanto i ahora vale 2.
             * valorQueSumo = 2, porque i = 2.
             * valorDeSumaAnterior = 1, porque cambió a ese valor en la primera pasada.
             * suma = 1 + 2; la suma vuelve a cambiar y ahora su valor es 3.
             */
            /*
             * Tercera pasada:
             * Ten en cuenta que i++ se ejecuto otra vez mas, por tanto i = 3, y el
             * valor de suma tambien cambio a 3.
             * Por tanto:
             * valorQueSumo = 3, porque i = 3.
             * valorDeSumaAnterior = 3, es el valor resultante de la segunda pasada.
             * suma = 3 + 3; Ahora suma, pasa a tener el valor de 6.
             */
            /*
             * Cuarta pasada:
             * Ten en cuenta que i++ se ejecuto otra vez mas, por tanto i = 4, y el
             * valor de suma tambien cambio a 6.
             * Por tanto:
             * valorQueSumo = 4, porque i = 4.
             * valorDeSumaAnterior = 6, es el valor resultante de la tercera pasada.
             * suma = 6 + 4; Ahora suma, pasa a tener el valor de 10.
             */
            // Y asi, consecutivamente, hasta que i++ llegue a 101, y ya no cumple: i <= 100.
        }
        System.out.println(suma);
    }
```